# How to make rank card on DiscordPy

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am coding a discord bot for my personal server. And I did a level system with JSON. But I want to send a rank card when you write the rank command. [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqP2s.png)

How can do that with progress bar? Do i need a base design? I've searched it before but result nothing without a information image which written with pillow...

My level system code is here. Thank you.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os

token: str = 'token'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

level_channel_name = 'bot-komut'



@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('Bot is ready')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    if not member.id in users:
        users[member.id] = {}
        users[member.id]['XP'] = 0
        users[member.id]['level'] = 1

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('.'):
        pass
    else:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        xp = genXP(message)
        print(xp)

        channel = discord.utils.get(client.channels, name=level_channel_name)

        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_xp(users, message.author, xp)
        await levelUp(users, message.author, channel)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)


    await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command()
async def rank(ctx):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    level = users[str(ctx.message.author.id)]['level']
    await ctx.send(f"""{level} Levelsin, {ctx.message.author.mention}""")

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

@client.event
async def update_data(users, user):
    if str(user.id) in users:
        pass
    else:
        print("Yeni kayıt")
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]['XP'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_xp(users, user, xp):
    users[str(user.id)]['XP'] += xp

async def levelUp(users, user, channel):
    lastxp = users[str(user.id)]['XP']
    startLevel = users[str(user.id)]['level']
    levelEnd = int(lastxp ** (1/6))

    if levelEnd > startLevel:
        await channel.send(f"""{user.mention}, {levelEnd} seviyeye ulaştı""")
        users[str(user.id)]['level'] = levelEnd


async def genXP(mesaj):
    msg = mesaj.content.split(" ")
    genedXP = len(msg)
    return genedXP

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Yes, you would use PIL/Pillow for something like this. You would have a base image to paste the user's avatar over and add text to.

Comment: @Cloud so how can i do progress bar for xp on pillow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **one image as background** and **one image as progress bar** and then change width of progress bar image based on your percentage:

```
from PIL import Image

# load background image
background = Image.open("background.jpg")

# load rectangle(progress bar)
rectangle = Image.open("rect.png")

# percentage of progress bar
percent = 70

# change width of progress bar based on percentage
rectangle = rectangle.resize((round(rectangle.size[0] * percent / 100), rectangle.size[1]))

# draw progress bar from x,y 50 of background image
background.paste(rectangle, (50, 50), rectangle)

# save image
background.save("result.png")
```

Comment: i did it like you said. It's nearly worked but i have a problem. I saved my rectangle image with png, but in result it looks like a jpg file. Corners are not transparent. What can i do to solve this?

Comment: Check code now, add third argument to paste function so that indicates a mask that will be used to paste the image. If you pass a image with transparency, then the alpha channel is used as mask.

Comment: Thanks again. I was solved it with 'mask=rectangle' on paste function, like this. Thank your so much again.

Comment: I'd like to add that if your progress bar image isn't that complicated, you could just draw it with [`ImageDraw.draw.rectangle`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle).

Comment: Can you provide some example pictures as i can't get a image required for this it is saying `bad transparency mask ` Please edit your answer